# Failed audit for making a valid comment?

Tags: discussion, comments, disputed-review-audits

I was given an audit that I felt didn't belong on StackOverflow, but perhaps would be a better fit on CodeReview. I made this comment to the question as it was still a well worded question and not in need of down-voting or deletion, but the OP should consider moving it to a more relevant location.

For making that comment I failed the audit because apparently asking people's opinion about how you wrote your code is an acceptable question on SO?

The question:
[more efficient type-level computations using type families?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26538595/more-efficient-type-level-computations-using-type-families)

Was this a bad audit or should I reconsider what is an appropriate question on SO?

I'm not sure why the question was up-voted so many times honestly, it doesn't belong on SO and I stand by my comment. I probably should have even flagged it in the audit.

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Comment: "Was this a bad audit or should I reconsider what is an appropriate question on SO?" is surely irrelevant. The issue is that making a comment shouldn't fail an audit ever.

Comment: No. The real issue was that this is a highly-upvoted bad question. It lacks code. Not sure if after adding code it would become on-topic for SO, but I think not.

Comment: @JanDvorak - Disagree. Seems wrong to me that adding a comment can ever be regarded as a reason for failure. Whether the question is good or bad. Except if SO have developed the technology to read the comment and decide whether the remark was reasonable.

Comment: This has been discussed before and the official stance is that if you comment without upvoting, the comment probably was probably criticism.

Comment: I see that often in the Haskell tag, lot of upvotes on questions that would be closed and/or downvoted in other tags. I always check the question if I stumble on a Haskell question in the queue....

Comment: @rene I (probably like many users) tend to be generous - lower threshold for votes, higher for flags - to questions in "smart" tags like Haskell due to a sense that they're somehow "inherently valuable" and more likely to improve the standard of discourse if they get more attention (although not this one... no code). This POV is probably wrong, but I believe its intent is in line with the greater mission.

Comment: My impression of this particular question is that it does state a specific question that's immediately understandable to interested Haskell experts. And like a lot of non-elementary Haskell questions, it might have a fascinating, valuable answer, or it might not. I had upvoted it when it was posted. I don't know about "inherently valuable", but the community's positive response to this question was not irrational.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Editing was the proper action there - the code is available, just not in the question. You'll find lots of non-audits in the First Post queue that make mistakes like this - that's why they're up for review.

Commenting is pretty useless by itself; I won't say you shouldn't leave comments, but you should nearly always do *something else* as well.

That said, we're rolling out a change that'll make it *slightly* more obvious when you try to comment on an audit.

Comment: When you say editing was the proper action, what exactly should have been edited? Or do you mean that generically as in "taking corrective action?" I feel like had I handled this 100% correctly I should have flagged it as belonging on another site or being off topic.

Comment: What happened to licenses? It's on lpaste, not on stackoverflow. Why would one be allowed to just copy it over?

Comment: So, if op would've edited the question, he would've passed the audit?. The message says "This was a high quality post and you should have considered **leaving it as-is**"

Comment: Yes, @lamak - editing would have passed the audit.

Comment: @Shog9 Well, that's a confusing message then

Comment: @Lamak: It does say "you should've *considered* leaving it as-is". That doesn't necessarily mean there cannot be other valid choices, too.

Answer (score 8):

Aside from the whole audit, please look at the site's help center before migrating.

[Code Review's help center topic about on-topic questions states the following:](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

> To be on-topic the answer must be "yes" to all questions:
>
> - Is code included directly in my question? (See Make sure you include your code in your question below.)
> - Am I an owner or maintainer of the code?
> - Is it actual code from a project rather than pseudo-code or example code?
> - Do I want the code to be good code? (i.e. not code-golfing, obfuscation, or similar)
> - To the best of my knowledge, does the code work?
> - Do I want feedback about any or all facets of the code?

The question fails #1. **Do not migrate it to Code Review, we will close the question without much thought.**

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the Stack Overflow help pages, there is **nothing there to say that if a question is on topic for Code Review then it's off topic here**.

This one needs nailing because it's increasingly coming back to bite. Lots of questions attract close votes and downvotes because the question would be appropriate for Code Review. We desperately need either

1. a clear statement in our help pages to the effect that if something is within the scope for Code Review then it's out of scope for Stack Overflow; or
2. a stop to all the attempts to kick questions out purely for being appropriate for Code Review.

(It sounds as though this one wasn't on topic for Code Review anyway, but that's tangential to the underlying problem that concerns me.)

Comment: That's… totally unrelated to the question.

Comment: @bjb568 no more so than pimgd's answer. The point is that the comment that failed the audit was along these lines.

Comment: So your answer is off-topic and a duplicate? … I agree with you, but Shog's answer is the only one that directly address the question.