# Failed audit because I commented

Tags: discussion, review-audits

I'll admit that I've been sloppy when it comes to reviewing and failed a number of audits in the past. I've been trying to step up my game.

I failed this last audit because I tried to leave a comment on the post.

https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/9745999

The comment I tried to leave said something like "you probably have to write your own List<> class" (I don't remember the exact wording). But apparently this was not the correct action to take, so I failed the audit.

I suppose this is because I was *reviewing* the question, and the thought is that all my comments should be related to the quality of the post. But I commented on the question in the review queue instead of clicking the link to the original post out of convenience.

Maybe I'm in the wrong. It just seems like failing an audit for making a comment is unfair. A comment could really contain anything. It could even be something that agrees with the perceived quality of the post. Should reviewers fail audits based on only the action of commenting?

---

[This question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277551/failed-audit-for-making-a-valid-comment) had a similar title, but it's protesting an audit rather than discussing whether failing audits for commenting is justified.