# Adding a comment says it's an audit?

Tags: discussion, review-audits

I was reviewing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/16174651) triage entry, which was an audit. When I saw that question, it had screenshots that were huge, and so I tried to post a comment saying that the OP should scale down his photos next time. When I clicked on the "add a comment" button, a dialog said "This is an audit, you cannot put comments" (something like that). In my opinion, if it was going to be an audit, this dialog should not pop up as it makes the reviewer know that it was an audit.

Comment: slightly related; https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277551/failed-audit-for-making-a-valid-comment

Comment: Usually they flat out refuse to tell you whether the thing that let you tell it was an audit was on purpose or not. You're actually kind of lucky there's a Meta post explaining this behavior.