# Banned (2-days) after review audit misclick

Tags: feature-request, review-audits

So I was reviewing some first posts and after a while I stumbled upon the following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/18654218). After reading it I wanted to upvote the question but by accident voted it down, after this it instantly closed the review and said I was banned for 2 days.

I understand that I have reviewed questions wrong before and action should be taken if this continues, but should it not be so that I have to confirm my decision by hitting next instead of being unable to change my decision and instantly temp-banning me?

Just like when you edit a question or comment underneath the question/answer it still allows you to click next or I'm done for example.

---

**Note**: I do not mean you should be able to change your decision afterwards. I just mean you should be able to confirm your actions.

Comment: I wanted to upvote to show my sympathy but now I accidentally downvoted.

Comment: @usr2564301 Luckily you can change it by just clicking upvote again :)

Comment: Its a bit questionable that you fail an audit because you downvoted - accidentally or otherwise. [It shouldn't matter how you vote](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277347/thesis-a-downvote-should-never-fail-a-first-post-audit).

Answer (score 9):

The point of these reviews are to check if the reviewer is paying attention.

I'd argue that accidentally downvoting instead of upvoting falls under the category of "Not paying attention". Adding confirmation steps everywhere, while 
"safe", is bad UX.

Allowing a user to revert an review action like that would completely remove the point of having audits.

> *"Stop, look and listen! <...>"*
>   - *Guess I failed that audit, let's try again.*

Then we might as well remove the audits altogether.

---

Your only option is to wait for the review ban to expire, you can then continue reviewing.

Comment: `I understand that I have reviewed questions wrong before and action should be taken if this continues` Like I said, I did fail audits before but hitting my mouse against my keyboard and accidentally clicking downvote does not mean I am not paying attention. And my opinion is that this should be reversible just like edits and comments.

Comment: Also I am not making a problem about being banned, Im just asking if it is possible for us to be able to change our decision instead of being instantly redirected and not given the chance to change our decision.

Comment: @Granny: Making audit actions reversible makes these audits meaningless. One could just revert and pick the right option on ___every single audit___.

Comment: Im also not saying that it should be possible to reverse an audit afterwards, I'm saying it should be possible to change your decision during the audit or before submitting your decision.

Comment: That would require an complete overhaul on SO's voting, editing, review, reputation and audit system. There isn't a single review action that doesn't take effect immediately.

Comment: I don't understand how making the review system so you have to confirm your actions after down/up voting takes a whole rework of voting, editing, review, reputation and audit system. Are the review queues not a separate system?

Comment: @Granny *Like I said, I did fail audits before but hitting my mouse against my keyboard and accidentally clicking downvote does not mean I am not paying attention* - let's think about this another way: "I failed my driving test twice and admit that, but when I failed the third one for putting the car in reverse and driving into a building when I meant it put in forward  gear isn't fair?"

Comment: @Granny: The actions you can perform in the review queue aren't separate from the rest of the site. They're the same vote / edit / flag actions, just from a different page. Adding a _"Are you sure?"_ confirmation to that isn't feasible.

Comment: Say the post is deleted. It's not possible to vote on deleted posts, and since the action should normally happen immediately it now can't because you're trying to do something you're not allowed to do. Therefore, the audit kicks in and fails you right away.

Comment: I don't really find it fair but sure if this is how it works and its impossible to change. Then so be it. Ill wait out the 2 days. Thank you

Comment: @Granny things *can change* (just slowly) - and sometimes audits *are unfair*... mods will release or otherwise reduce bans involved. There's just no reason to do so here (not just from this but review history wise) - perhaps you should spend the two days making sure your mouse doesn't walk on your keyboard? :p

Comment: @JonClements Ill try to keep the two away from each other :)

Comment: @Cerbrus I slightly disagree on "The actions you can perform in the review queue aren't separate from the rest of the site" as you can cancel an upvote/downvote during a small period of time on a normal post. BTW I agree there's no reason to add complexity to the the review system.

Comment: @Tensibai: Yes, but that's no different in a review queue. You can still cancel the up/downvote there. It's exactly the same logic / code. The only "problem" is that the audit immediately responds to a taken action. But I don't see a simple "fix" there. What if a user closes the review after voting?

Comment: @Cerbrus I fully agree it works as expected and there's nothing to change :) Just the behavior is a little different when the response fire immediately. I think we have a queue with a button "I'm done" which could be implemented, but I really see no reason, failing one audit for a misclick is something, getting a ban is too much misclick anyway and is just another warning for "pay extra attention in review".

Comment: @Tensibai: ___Voting___ behavior is _no different_ between the review queue and a notmal question page. The `[I'm done]` button is _only_ available when you haven't taken an invalid action yet. Clicking "Edit" on a audit where editing is incorrect also ___immediately___ triggers an audit failure. _Any_ wrong action on _any_ audit immediately fails the audit. the fact that a `[I'm done]` button lights up means you haven't done anything wrong, yet. Besides, no _single_ miss-click can get you review banned.

Comment: I still agree @Cerbrus, the voting behavior is the same, the interface behavior is not and that could be surprising the _first_ time. My last sentence was probably bad, I mean one need multiple miss-click to get a ban and that's worthy of a ban.

Comment: How is the interface behavoir different, and from what, @Tensibai? I don’t think I’m getting your point.

Comment: The fact you can't "cancel", but nevermind, that's not very important :)

Comment: You can't cancel votes on a normal question either... There is no "pending" step in votes.

Comment: @Cerbrus You can switch up until a certain amount of time. Or is that not what you meant?

Comment: I mean that you can’t have a “pending” up / downvote that’s applied after clocking some “done” button.

Comment: @Cerbrus Alright

Answer (score 3):

I think I might have expressed this idea in the past, but in my opinion, an audit should complete when you click "I'm done" or "No Action needed", and not the second you click anything.

Not only would doing that solve the issue the OP is having, but it would also more faithfully emulate a real review.

Comment: Exactly what i meant. But I guess if something is hard to change or takes alot of work your question gets downvoted into oblivion.

Comment: '"honeypot" is intended to catch "fake reviewers" - those abusing review actions with the purpose (P-U-R-P-O-S-E) to increase their review count. The only way to increase review count in First Posts and Late Answers queues is to click specific button(s) like I'm Done or No Action Needed - as long as this did not happen, it is wrong to assume test completed...' ([“STOP! Look and Listen” audit tricked me](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/156942/165773))

Answer (score 2):

First of all: I don't see why you fail an audit because you downvoted. That's just wrong, voting is your personal freedom and this makes it appear like you shouldn't have downvoted even if that was a mistake. The only thing you did wrong was doing it from a review queue which is a feature that apparently was on the radar to [be removed a long time ago](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277347/thesis-a-downvote-should-never-fail-a-first-post-audit), but it never was. Not exactly your fault that it wasn't.

Secondly: Commenting had the same problem - and that problem has been fixed in a rather amusing way as documented here: [Failed audit for making a valid comment?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277551/failed-audit-for-making-a-valid-comment)

(if you try to comment, the site blocks you and tells you it's an audit)

Push comes to shove my personal opinion here is that this shouldn't be brushed off the table so easily, you didn't do anything wrong and your ban should have been lifted.

Comment: I also found that post and also read through it. I was thinking about mentioning it but did not do it anyway.

Comment: Well I already commented it, but I decided to upgrade to a full answer when yesterday the second link about comments was presented to me.